# Make a child view wider than it's parent view without setting an absolute width?

Tags: android, layout

How would one go about making the child view wider than the parent without using an absolute width?

The following XML results in the child views dimensions getting constrained by the parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="800dp" 
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_border" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

If I set an absolute width for the parent layout then the child does not get constrained.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="800dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="800dp" 
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_border" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thats the way it supposed to work, why would you want one of your views to go outside its parent? Or are you trying to make like a sliding view? Try using the ScrollView

Comment: The child view handles touch gestures and you can pan and pinch zoom. The contents of the child are much larger than the screen width. A scroll view will not allow the desired panning/diagonal scrolling.

Comment: i think what you want is a canvas, which you draw whatever you are needing pinched/panned on SurfaceView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html